# How to retrieve values from 2 different input forms with the dynamically same named array PHP

Tags: php, html

I have 2 types of input wrapped in a loop, the first one has a Radio button type, the other one Textarea.

For radio buttons, I give the same dynamic name to group options with one another with an array type (for example: `name = 'arr[$idgabung]'`).

And for Textarea I also give the name `name = 'arr[$idgabung]'`

`$idgabung` contains unique id, example: `U1Q1`, So I can distinguish each radio button based on the value of each after the loop.

**Sample code:**

```
<div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="custom-controls-stacked">
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                  <?php echo "<input name='arr[$idgabung]' id='$idgabung.1' type='radio' required='required' class='custom-control-input' value='1'>"; ?>
                  <?php echo "<label for='$idgabung.1' class='custom-control-label'><i class='fas fa-star'></i></label>"; ?>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-controls-stacked">
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                  <?php echo "<input name='arr[$idgabung]' id='$idgabung.2' type='radio' required='required' class='custom-control-input' value='2'>"; ?>
                  <?php echo "<label for='$idgabung.2' class='custom-control-label'><i class='fas fa-star'></i><i class='fas fa-star'></i></label>"; ?>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-controls-stacked">
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                  <?php echo "<input name='arr[$idgabung]' id='$idgabung.3' type='radio' required='required' class='custom-control-input' value='3'>"; ?>
                  <?php echo "<label for='$idgabung.3' class='custom-control-label'><i class='fas fa-star'></i><i class='fas fa-star'></i><i class='fas fa-star'></i></label>"; ?>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-controls-stacked">
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                  <?php echo "<input name='arr[$idgabung]' id='$idgabung.4' type='radio' required='required' class='custom-control-input' value='4'>"; ?>
                  <?php echo "<label for='$idgabung.4' class='custom-control-label'><i class='fas fa-star'></i><i class='fas fa-star'></i><i class='fas fa-star'></i><i class='fas fa-star'></i></label>"; ?>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-controls-stacked">
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                  <?php echo "<input name='arr[$idgabung]' id='$idgabung.5' type='radio' required='required' class='custom-control-input' value='5'>"; ?>
                  <?php echo "<label for='$idgabung.5' class='custom-control-label'><i class='fas fa-star'></i><i class='fas fa-star'></i><i class='fas fa-star'></i><i class='fas fa-star'></i><i class='fas fa-star'></i></label>"; ?>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  
<div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
          <label>Deskripsi</label>
          <?php echo "<textarea  class='form-control' rows='3' name='arr[$idgabung]' placeholder=''></textarea>"; ?>
      </div>
</div>
```

I wrap this input form in a loop and supply it with the data I have prepared, then I can retrieve the values ​​from the Radio button and Textarea in this way:

```
foreach($this->input->post("arr") as $arr_id => $arr_val)
{
    echo 'ID:'. $ arr_id. ", Value:". $ arr_val. "<br>";
}
```

But the problem is the Textarea value always overwrites the value taken from the Radio button selection result, maybe because it uses the same name?

What I want is, I can get their values ​​all at once in the same array without overlapping each other.

How do you name the correct form name?
And how do you take their values without overlapping one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it a bit:

A) Change `name` of radio button to `arr[$idgabung][key]`

B) Change `name` of textArea to `arr[$idgabung][value]`

Now change PHP code like below:

```
foreach($this->input->post("arr") as $arr_val)
{
    echo 'ID:'. $arr_val['key']. ", Value:". $arr_val['value']. "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks you save me, it works! I just need to write `[key]` without `''` (because I wrote it inside `<? Php echo?>`), And also I still need the dynamic array name inside the loop, like: `foreach ($this->input->post("arr") as $arr_id => $arr_val)`